# How to use state in great grand parent in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

What is the easiest way to set state from 4 components below the first component?

- First {name}
- Second
- Third
- Fourth {setName}

In fourth component I want to set name and then use it in the first component to render the name like {name}

```
const First = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
<div>
  <div>{name}
  <Second />
</div>
}

const Second = () => {
 <div>
  <Third />
 </div>
}

const Third = () => {
 <div>
  <Fourth />
 </div>
}

const Fourth = () => {
 <div>
  <div onClick={()=>setName(something.name)}>{something.name). 
  </div>
 </div>
}
```

Comment: It's hard to make any recommendations without code. Please may you update the question with a [mcve]?

Comment: how about using props?

Comment: check out [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by passing `setName` as a prop from the `First` component to the `Fourth`

```
const First = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  return (
    <div>
      {name}
      <Second setFirstName={(name) => setName(name)} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Second = ({ setFirstName }) => {
  return (
   <div>
     <Third setFirstName={setFirstName}/>
   </div>)
}

const Third = ({ setFirstName }) => {
 return (
  <div>
    <Fourth setFirstName={setFirstName}/>
  </div>
 )
}

const Fourth = ({ setFirstName }) => {
 return (
   <div>
     <div onClick={() => setFirstName('Test Name')}>Press to set Name</div>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the fourth component you can have a `handleNameChange(newName)` prop to lift the state up.

```
const FourthComponent = (
  name: string,
  handleNameChanged: (newName: string) => void
) = {
  const onNameChanged = (newName: string) => handleNameChanged(newName)
}
```

Same in third and second components to lift up in the same way.

Finally, in the first one you will have something like :

```
const FirstComponent = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('')

  <SecondComponent
    name={name}
    handleNameChange={(name) => setNAme(name)}
  />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case you want to pass a variable to a parent, you just pass it via a `prop` function:

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [var, setVar] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`${var} in parent`);

    return (
        <Child passVarToParent={setVar} />
    );
}

const Child = (props) => {
    return (
        <input /* ... */ onChange={(e) => props.passVarToParent(e.target.value)} />
    );
}
```

However, in case of parent-child-chaining, I'd go with some state management like `Redux`, `MobX` or `React Context`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subject between state sharing among parent and child (I mean `props` and `emit`) and state management (as `redux`). This subject is called `Event Bus`.
There is an example of your code managing data with `Event Bus`:

```
const eventBus = {
  on(event, callback) {
    document.addEventListener(event, (e) => callback(e.detail));
  },
  dispatch(event, data) {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(event, { detail: data }));
  },
  remove(event, callback) {
    document.removeEventListener(event, callback);
  },
};
class First extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {      
      name: "",    
    };  
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    eventBus.on("name", (data) =>
      this.setState({ name: data.name })
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    eventBus.remove("name");
  }
return (<div>
          <div>{name}
          <Second />
        </div>)
}
const Second = () => {
 <div>  
   <Third />
 </div>}
const Third = () => {
  <div>  
    <Fourth /> 
  </div>
}
const Forth = () => { 
  <div>
    <div onClick={()=>eventBus.dispatch("name", { name: "name changed" });}>{something.name). 
    </div>
  </div>
}
```